# Sending local/ubiquitous documents to opposite location and avoid double-named documents

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument

My document-based app makes use of iCloud. Just as Apple suggest in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW3) I automatically create document names based on existing documents i.e Notes 1, Notes 2, Notes 3 etc. and move documents between the local and ubiquitous store when the user switches iCloud on/off.

The problem is if I create a local Document (let’s say ‘Notes 1’) then the user switches on iCloud, it’s possible that there is already a 'Notes 1’ named document there which is moved to the same directory as my local Notes 1.

Answer (score 0):

Apple’s solution (in Pages for iOS) is to rename, I think the newest, document by incrementing the name to the next available one